# Create Task from Object

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
public Task<Envelope<Response>> Handle(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

  List<Error> errors = _validator.Validate(request));

  if (errors.Any()) 
    return new Envelope<Response>(errors);

  return _handler.Handle(request, cancellationToken);

}
```

If there are any errors I need to to return `Envelope<Response>(errors)`.

The problem is the method returns `Task<Envelope<Response>>`.

How to create and return the Task?

Comment: How common are errors? Maybe you should consider using [Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions) instead.

Comment: I do not want to use Exceptions as these are Model Validation errors. I was able to solve it with Task.FromResult: return Task.FromResult<Envelope<Response>>(new Envelope<Response>(errors));